# Reading Guitar Hero or Rock Band Controllers from a PC

Tags: usb

The "instruments" that are used with Guitar Hero and Rock Band have USB connections.  Is there any documentation or reverse-engineering info out there about how to read the messages they generate?

Comment: You should really state which console you are getting your controllers from, since that really makes a difference.

Comment: a favorite question for Jeff?

Comment: Old, old question, but in case anyone stumbles upon this later - try Dark Basic. It'll automatically pick up your input devices and manipulation is easy. I wrote a 30-line drum program and it works great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Wiiuse](http://www.wiiuse.net/?nav=docs) - it suppors the Guitar Hero 3 controller, as well as Wiimotes :)

Answer (score 4):

This message may be too old to be useful.

I was hacking around with an old Nyko 3rd party Guitar Hero / Rock Band PS3 controller on a laptop running Ubuntu 10.04 (2.6.32-25) and I discovered that the hardware was not recognized immediately by the USB HID module. It reports an error of: "can't set config #1, error -32".

I began writing a small test application with libusb-1.0 and was able to apply a configuration directly. Upon doing so, I unintentionally triggered the USB HID module taking over the device and making it available as an input device through a /dev/input/js* interface.

Answer (score 2):

From my Google searches, the Guitar Hero and Rock Band controllers are USB HID devices.  This means they should plug and play on most any machine that supports HID (most do).  See USB Revealed by Jan Axelseon for more information.

Comment: I would assume that it use HID as a basic transport and have a proprietary report descriptor that can be recorded and analyzed using usb bus analyzer (just google for it lecroy and ellisys are most popular) or you can check if linux supporting this :)

Answer (score 1):

You could check [Frets on Fire](http://fretsonfire.sourceforge.net/) project. It's opensource GH-like game, and as far as I remember documentation said you could use Guitar Hero controller instead of the keyboard.

Here's some additional semi-info: [Frets on Fire and the 360 Guitar](http://kotaku.com/gaming/guitar-hero/frets-on-fire-and-the-360-guitar-249579.php).

Answer (score 1):

I tried the GH3 controller on my WinXP machine and it appeared as an HID device - and appears as a game controller - so I suspect most of the work is already done for you.

Try it and see...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can ping these guys for info?

- http://www.dxprog.com/entry/rock-band-drums-on-windows/
- http://andrewrudson.com/drummachine/main.php